# 'rake spec' works, 'spec spec' doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, macports

When I added my first gem dependency to `config/environment.rb`, (`will_paginate`), I'm encountering an error when running rspec as follows:

```
nik$ spec spec/
Missing these required gems:
  will_paginate  

You're running:
  ruby 1.8.6.369 at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.7 at /Users/nik/.gem/ruby/1.8, /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8, /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

It's not picking up the first `ruby` binary in my $PATH, which I installed with macports:

```
nik$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-darwin9]
nik$ which ruby
/opt/local/bin/ruby
```

Curiously, `rake spec` succeeds:

```
nik$ rake spec
(in /Users/nik/rails_projects/bigchan)
....................................................................................

Finished in 2.314131 seconds

84 examples, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different commands looking up different versions of ruby, hence - different sets of gems.

```
$ which -a ruby
```

will show you at least two versions of ruby.

- ruby 1.8.6.369 probably in `/usr/bin` (used when running `spec spec/`)
- ruby 1.8.7.299 in `/opt/local/bin` (used when running `rake spec`)

Nuke the one you don't need and everything related to it.